# Unable to call bloc event with MultiBlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am using a MultiBlocProvider with location bloc which will give me location and then use the location to get weather detail from different bloc. I tried to use the blocs but somehow bloc event is not being called even in location bloc. Following is my main file:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<GeolocationBloc>(create: (context) => locator<GeolocationBloc>()),
        BlocProvider<WeatherInfoBloc>(create: (context) => locator<WeatherInfoBloc>()),
      ], child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      home: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: WeatherInfoPage(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
```

Following is my WeatherInfoPage where I want to use both blocs:

```
class WeatherInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherInfoPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeatherInfoPage> createState() => _WeatherInfoPageState();
}

class _WeatherInfoPageState extends State<WeatherInfoPage> {
  late WeatherInfoBloc _weatherInfoBloc;
  late GeolocationBloc _geolocationBloc;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _weatherInfoBloc = locator<WeatherInfoBloc>();
    _geolocationBloc = locator<GeolocationBloc>()..add(LoadGeolocationEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<GeolocationBloc, GeolocationState>(
      // bloc: _geolocationBloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is GeolocationLoading) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),//debugger stuck here
          );
        } else if (state is GeolocationLoaded) {
          _weatherInfoBloc.add(WeatherInfoFetchEvent());
          return WeatherDisplayPage();
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }

}

class WeatherDisplayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherDisplayPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeatherDisplayPage> createState() => _WeatherDisplayPageState();
}

class _WeatherDisplayPageState extends State<WeatherDisplayPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<WeatherInfoBloc, WeatherInfoState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is WeatherInfoInitial || state is WeatherInfoFetchingState) {
            return _buildLoading();
          } else if (state is WeatherInfoFetchingSuccessState) {
            return _buildWeatherForcastView(context, state.weatherInfoList);
          }
          return Container();
        }
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWeatherForcastView(BuildContext context, List<WeatherInfoViewModel> weatherInfoList) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text(weatherInfoList.first.day ?? "")),
        Text(weatherInfoList.first.weather ?? ""),
        Image.asset(weatherInfoList.first.titleImage),
        Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text(weatherInfoList.first.temp ?? "")),
        Text(weatherInfoList.first.pressure.toString()),
        Text(weatherInfoList.first.wind.toString()),
        SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return ForecastTile(
                  weatherInfoViewModel: weatherInfoList[index],
                );
              },
              itemCount: weatherInfoList.length,
            )
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoading() => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Debugger is able to reach only in loading of location bloc which is default state but the event is not running.

Edit:
Injection container:

```
    final locator = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> initializeDependencies() async {
  locator.registerFactory(() => WeatherInfoBloc(locator()));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<WeatherInfoUseCase>(() => WeatherInfoUseCase(weatherInfoRepository: locator()));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<WeatherInfoRepository>(() => WeatherInfoRepositoryImpl(weatherInfoRemoteDataSource: locator()));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<WeatherInfoRemoteDataSource>(() => WeatherInfoRemoteDataSourceImpl(client: locator()));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<BaseClient>(() => BaseClient());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => http.Client());
  locator.registerFactory(() => GeolocationBloc(locator()));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<GeolocationRepository>(() => GeolocationRepository());
}
```

Comment: What is your function or class `locator()` ? So your state is not changing?

Comment: This is for dependency injection, I have added as Edit

Comment: Where do you emit the new state? From what I see here, it doesn't look like anything is emitted in response to user input. So I would recommend taking a closer look at whatever code causes the GeolocationLoaded state to be emited.